# Should the question asking for articles on writing a good job description for a web developer position have been closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

[This is the question I'm referring to](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143845/any-good-articles-on-how-to-write-a-good-job-description-for-a-web-developer-pos).

Are developers the best suited for answering questions about job postings for developers? Should the question therefore have been left open?

Comment: You really should post an answer stating your own opinion on the matter instead of including it in with your question. That way it can be judged/evaluated separately from the question itself. Otherwise, the only answers you'll get are ones disagreeing with you, and people will look at your question and say nobody agrees with you despite the fact the question itself may get many upvotes.

Comment: @Rachel - Apparently I was wrong about how this worked.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

The question is one that a HR person would most likely *ask*. But wouldn't programmers be the best at *answering* it? What % of programmers think they can do a better job than HR at writing a job posting?

I'll admit the question asked for references to articles answering the question, rather than direct answers. In this case I think the direct question would be better.

But I imagine it would have been closed anyway.

So, are programmers the people best suited to write job postings for programming positions? If so, should the question have been closed?  I think the question should have been left open, but ideally edited to ask the real question directly instead of asking for references to articles.

Comment: not sure that programmers actually ever would be the best to answer a question like this, but I would say we think we are.

Comment: @Ryathal - (begin working on my Area 51 proposal for knowitalls.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular instance, the question is badly worded and provides very little context, so I think an HR manager would be better at giving general advice for the job posting tips the OP is asking for.

The only thing I think programmers could answer better is perhaps job title advice based on what someone is looking for, or perhaps advice on what development details that should go into the posting based on actual project requirements.

Of course, the faq states this site is about conceptual questions on software development, in which case this question wouldn't belong, however it also states that some career advice questions are on-topic, providing it's unique to developers.

I usually don't vote to close unless something clearly doesn't belong here, and would be happy to help you re-open it providing you edit the question so it requires the unique expertise of a programmer.

Comment: I linked to this question.  If the OP wants to try to walk the line of being specific enough to be answerable but of general value I'll see what I can do.